# How has Microsoft sent me an email with AJAX in it?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, email, outlook

I just received this email which I hadn't noticed coming through before. It reads your messages in 365 and prompts about possibly outstanding tasks. When I clicked <kbd>Done</kbd> on the first task, the options hid and *Completed* was immediately displayed in the email window.

How have they done this? Is this 365 magic or is it possible to do with HTML/JS?

Right-click is also completely disabled on the message.

[image]

Comment: Try opening the email in another client like Thunderbird and see if it does the same? I suspect it's just 365, though - Microsoft are well known for breaking compatibility with normal email clients for adding minor things.

Comment: @VLAZ On Mail for Mac the buttons are removed, along with the Schedule below - https://i.stack.imgur.com/UR7xz.png However I'd be curious to know if this is possible to do for Outlook specifically.